# failed archiving ipa files jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins

I have a extrange problem,

when building the ios app with jenkins the ipa file is generated, and signed correctly but when I try to archive the ipa file it fails

the jenkins log says

```
Results at '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iosHelp/workspace/build/ipa/Verion.ipa' 
[Debug-iphoneos] $ ditto -c -k --keepParent -rsrc /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iosHelp/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/FormSlider.app.dSYM /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iosHelp/workspace/build/ipa/Verion-dSYM.zip
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iosHelp/workspace/build/ipa/Verion.ipa". Configuration error?
ERROR: ‘/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iosHelp/workspace/build/ipa/Verion.ipa’ doesn’t match anything: ‘’ exists but not ‘/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iosHelp/workspace/build/ipa/Verion.ipa’
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

clearly it states that jenkins couldn't find the ipa but in the statement before shows that the ipa was generated also using the terminal to go to the build/ipa directory I cheked that the file currently exists and is generated,

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you use in your "Archive Artifacts" configuration? It should be **relative** to `$workspace`, so in your case just `build/ipa/Verion.ipa`.

Make sure there are no extra quotes either

Comment: That's exactly match what I have on the set up and is failing!! it doesn't find the ipa file

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to this job folder is there a file there? If you are using Ant blob syntax try adding a "*" at the end in case the file extension you wrote in is incorrect or instead of "build/ipa/Verion.ipa" use "build/ipa/Verion*" to try and locate the file, as @Slav mentioned use a path relative to the $workspace